Tailwind config for indirect dependency
According to the official documentation

If you’ve created your own reusable set of components that are styled with Tailwind and are importing them in multiple projects, make sure to configure Tailwind to scan those components for class names:

// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
    './node_modules/@my-company/components/src/**/*.js',
  ],
  // ...
}

But let's say @my-company/components depends on another package which is tailwind-based, @shared. Hence, the dependency tree is:
- my-app
  - @my-company/components
    - @shared

How should we define the tailwind.config.js in this case, such that Tailwind is able to generate the class names from @shared?

You'll have to add the relative path of the particular folder/file with extension.
Like this:
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
    './node_modules/@my-company/components/src/**/*.js',
    './@my-company/components/@shared/**/*.{html,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'
  ],
  // ...
}


But then this requires the developer to be aware of every indirect dependencies that are Tailwind-based, and manually list them out in tailwind.config.js? I think it's not really ideal.

In that case, you can just set the content to ["./src/**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}",] to work tailwind for every file with the provided extension.
